# How to do passing data to Activity from icon ToolBar

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to pass data from `autocomplete` in the `ToolBar` to other `Activity`.

This is my code where I am passing `intent` from `ToolBar` to other `Activity`.

```
 int buttonMap = item.getItemId();
        if (buttonMap == R.id.actionBar_map) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Maps.class);
            intent.putExtra("cityName", mAutoCompleteTextView.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
```

and this is my code from other `Activity`:

```
  if(getSupportActionBar()!=null){

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My Trip To " + getIntent().getExtras().getString("cityName"));
```

This is the `Activity` that shows the name of the city in `ToolBar`:

[image: Activity that Data is passing]

and this is the `Activity` to which the data is not passing :

[image: the second <code>Activity</code> from icon on <code>ToolBar</code> and I need that name of the city to appear]

I expect that a name of the city appears here.

Comment: Try to use `getIntent().getStringExtra("cityName");` see will that solve the issue

Comment: Put some logs to ensure that mAutoCompleteTextView.getText().toString() is returning what you expect

Comment: I try but is not work to me...

Comment: my problem is't slove, someone can ples help me do fix it??

Comment: For showing the string in the second Activity, you'd just set the title of the ActionBar. It's that simple!